USB floppy drive stops working under Ubuntu; USB warnings on bootup
I have two floppy drives (for 3.5" disks) and I use both from Windows, even at the same time. But one of the drives is not getting along with Ubuntu.
The drives are physically similar and are laptop modules that can be used as standalone USB floppy drives. Both are connected internally to one USB 2.0 motherboard header, by means of a small adapter accepting 2 USB-A cables.
The "good" drive is a SONY MPF82E.
The "bad" drive is branded as a Dell FDDM-101 and is a NEC USB UF000x.
The bad drive can work in Ubuntu. But, after I boot into Ubuntu a couple of times, the drive seems to stop working. I then have to turn my motherboard power off for a few seconds and reboot to get the drive back to normal. (Just rebooting into Windows won't fix it.)
On an initial bootup from a powered-off state I see this in 'sudo dmesg'
usb3-6.2: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
usb3-6.2: New device found, idVendor=0409, idProduct=0040, bcdDevice=1.50
usb3-6.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, Serial Number=0
usb3-6.2: Product: NEC USB UF000x
usb3-6.2: Manufacturer: NEC

There is a weird complaint from dmesg:
usb: port power management may be unreliable

Then after booting a couple of times, when the disk is not working, I
see this and the drive disappears from Linux and from Windows.
usb 3-6.2: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
usb 3-6.2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
usb 3-6.2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
usb 3-6.2: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
usb 3-6.2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
usb 3-6.2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
usb 3-6.2: new full-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
usb 3-6.2: Device not responding to setup address.
usb 3-6.2: Device not responding to setup address.
usb 3-6.2: device not accepting address 6, error -71
usb 3-6.2: new full-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
usb 3-6.2: Device not responding to setup address.
usb 3-6.2: Device not responding to setup address.
usb 3-6.2: device not accepting address 7, error -71

Is this a problem with motherboard power? A problem with a cable? A flaw in the drive? A bug in Ubuntu? I can use both drives simultaneously on Windows and reboot Windows and there isn't a problem.
I've seen only one time before where you have shut off all power to fix a USB device: it was a long time ago with an AFT Pro-55U smart card reader that had an incompatibility with a program speedfan.exe that would do unusual things with the motherboard. I had to use speedfan.exe /NOSMARTSCAN to avoid that problem. It makes me suspect Ubuntu is doing something "bad" to the motherboard or USB devices, that Windows deftly avoids. Or, maybe the USB device is complaining about something and Ubuntu gives up whereas Windows judiciously ignores the complaint.

This will be hard to troubleshoot, as the problem is intermediate. I think your last line "Maybe the USB device is complaining about something and Ubuntu gives up whereas Windows judiciously ignores the complaint." sounds like a good guess.

Sounds like power insufficiency.  Power draw depends on what each USB floppy is doing..When both are demanding, the voltage drops below threshold,  and the USB starts again when the power cones back.

"Sounds like power insufficiency" - Both drives show 5V 0.5A (2.5W) on their labels; so the total wattage is 5W. That should work fine on a USB 2.0 motherboard header. Possibly the power demand is increased by the adapter I'm using (2 x USB Type-A -to- motherboard header). Both drives run fine at the same time under Windows. It's still worth investigating, though.
